# How to re-initiate a function to change a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, single-page-application

In my function, I am using a variable (link) which gets the `ID` value from a row in my `datatable` to use in the `Ajax` URL when an element in the row is clicked. then on hover, the bootstrap popover opens to display an array from another table matching the `ID` value.

This works perfectly the first time, but I need to reinitiate the function for every row in the `datatable`. At the moment it just keeps showing the array for the first element I click on.

> datatable column

```
{ data: null, 
      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      if (data.imagecount3.count == null){ 

      return '<div style=" width:100%; font-size:13px; text-align:left;">0 / 0</div>'}

      else if (data.imagecount3.count == data.filecounter.Counter) {           

      return '<div style=" width:100%; font-size:13px; color:#1ABB9C; font-weight:bold; text-align:left;">'+data.filecounter.Counter+' / '+data.imagecount3.count+'</div>'}

      else {           

      return '<div style=" width:100%; font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><a data-toggle="popover" href="ajax.php?var='+data.macleanf.id+'" class="ajax_link">'+data.filecounter.Counter+' / '+data.imagecount3.count+'</a></div>'}



      }},
```

> PHP connection

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX","company");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['var']);


$sql=$con->query("SELECT Title FROM tblgalleryimages2 WHERE GalleryID='$var'");
//fetch tha data from the database
while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
   echo $row{'Title'};
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

> script

```
$('#yamba_overview').on( 'click', 'a.ajax_link', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

        var link=$(this).attr('href');

 $.ajax({ //Make the ajax request
      url: link,
      cache: false
    }).done(function(html) { //On complete run tooltip code


$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(

{title: "Missing Documents", 
trigger: "hover",
content: html});

    });



 });
```

Comment: show how you are populating the datable column.

Comment: I have updated the datatable code to include the entire code for the column. The column is rendering fine and the datatable uses its own PHP connector to render the table

Comment: can you inspect using dev tools if the elements rendered have respective id. coz it seems your code is all right.

Comment: When I preview the ajax requests after clicking the 'a.ajax_link' attribute on different rows (different macleanf.id values) it is returning the correct data for the row. However the html in the popover does not change and only shows the data from the first row I click, rather than reinitiate the function for every click. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT TO SCRIPT

figured it out with success: in ajax

```
$('#yamba_overview').on( 'mouseenter', 'a.ajax_link', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

        var link=$(this).attr('ajax_attr');

 $.ajax({ //Make the ajax request
      url: link,
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }
    })
    .done(function() { //On complete run tooltip code


$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(

{title: "Missing Documents", 
trigger: "click",
html: true,
content: function() {
      return $('.result').html();
    }
});
 });
  });
```